# Dropdowns in custom VSCode view container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to add custom UI - for example a dropdown - to the view container title, similar to how the *Debug* view container shows a dropdown of *launch.json* configurations?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Visual Studio code does not support any standard HTML to be used in the parts of it that can be extended by an extension. Webviews would allo such kind of UI, but they cannot be used as general UI extension, only as different document type.

Comment: The same day I read your answer, I noticed that Visual Studio Code 1.50 now supports [custom webviews in the sidebar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-view-sample) :)

Comment: Ah, very interesting! I have once opened an FR there to allow webviews in the sidebar. This was then merged to this discussion, but I haven't followed it anymore. That's a good step forward how webviews can be integrated soon, but still this is only a partial solution: "Webview views are contributed the same way as normal tree views which can either go into the side bar or panel by default.", which still means you cannot accomplish what you want here (you would have to implement an own treeview then).

Comment: You're right, it still won't help me achieve exactly what I want to do, but being able to have custom UI in a treeview is a good step. Thanks!